# Driving bandpass DSM with tone close to full-scale - stability issue?

Tags: fft, matlab, dft, delta-sigma

I am experimenting with Dr. Schreier's DSM toolbox for MATLAB. I stumbled over a strange phenomenon when having a look at a bandpass DSM in demo-script 2. If I increased the amplitude of the test-tone in one of the demo scripts from 0.5 full-scale to 0.9 full-scale, the DSM would seemingly become unstable (a totally distorted FFT). Shouldn't it be possible to drive the DSM until full-scale?

In the below FFT of the DSM output, you see the spectrum of 0.5 full-scale, looking as expected, noise around f0 greatly suppressed. With 0.9 full-scale, there is suddenly lots of noise around f0.

[image]

[image]

```
clear all; close all;

N = 1024 * 8;
f = linspace(0,0.5,N/2+1);

f0 = 1/8; OSR=64;
H = synthesizeNTF(8,OSR,1,[],f0);
fB = ceil(N/(2*OSR)); ftest=round(f0*N);
u1 = 0.5*sin(2*pi*ftest/N*[0:N-1]); % half-scale sine-wave input
u2 = 0.9*sin(2*pi*ftest/N*[0:N-1]);
v1 = simulateDSM(u1,H);
v2 = simulateDSM(u2,H);

figure(1); clf;
t = 0:100;
stairs(t, u1(t+1),'r');
hold on;
stairs(t,v1(t+1),'g');
axis([0 100 -1.2 1.2]);
xlabel('Sample Number');
ylabel('u, v');
title('Modulator Input & Output');

echo on
spec1 = fft(v1.*ds_hann(N))/(N/4);
spec2 = fft(v2.*ds_hann(N))/(N/4);
fft_sine = fft(u1)/(N/4);
echo off;
figure(2); clf;
plot(linspace(0,0.5,N/2+1), dbv(spec1(1:N/2+1)))
hold on;
plot(linspace(0,0.5,N/2+1), dbv(spec2(1:N/2+1)))
plot(linspace(0,0.5,N/2+1), dbv(fft_sine(1:N/2+1)))
axis([0 0.5 -140 0]);
f1 = round((f0-0.25/OSR)*N);
f2 = round((f0+0.25/OSR)*N);
snr = calculateSNR(spec1(f1:f2),ftest-f1+1);
% text(0.15,-10, sprintf(' SNR = %4.1f dB @ OSR=%d)',snr,OSR), 'vert','middle');
grid on;
xlabel('Normalized Frequency')
ylabel('dBFS/NBW')
xlim([0.05 0.2])
title('Output Spectrum');

echo on
NBW = 1.5/N;
Sqq = 4 * evalTF(H,exp(2i*pi*f)).^2 / 3;
echo off
hold on;
plot( f, dbp(Sqq*NBW), 'Linewidth', 2 );
text(0.5, -90, sprintf('NBW=%4.1E x f_s ',NBW),'Hor','right','Vert','mid');
legend('0.5 full-scale', '0.9 full-scale', 'test tone at f0', 'expected PSD');
```

Comment: Without knowing very much about the delta sigma modulator simulation you're using, I'll just say that clipping/clamping in the time domain would cause intermodulation products and this sort of spectral splatter. What do your time domain input and output plots look like?

Comment: Added the time plot from the code, I'll have a look if I can identify such clipping somewhere in the code, I was surprised to encounter this issue though, because its apparently a widely used toolbox for DSM design and I was just running a demo code

Comment: Stair plots are going to hide clipping, since a clip looks like a flat top.  It will probably be obvious with a normal plot that doesn't flatten output plots.  Also you probably don't want to decimate the time axis when looking for clipping in the data.